# Send a UIScrollView to printer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `scrollView` having multiple subview like detail invoices. I want to convert my `scrollView` into pdf so that i can easily send it to printer as well as send it via email. How can we do this? Is there any possible or easy way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Uiview` to do this. so first you should add uiview in scrollview and then your other content on that view. you can make method something like,

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

// Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


// draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

// remove PDF rendering context
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

// Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

// instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
}
```

Call this method, pass `uiview` (from which you want to make pdf) and string means file name. this method will create pdf and will store the data to documents directory. if you don't want to store then comment that portion.

you can display `pdfdata` to `webview` like,

```
 [webview loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: but sir have have multiple invoice data..
Let me explain you.. A UIView which is equivalent to self.view by size but this single UIView is representing a single invoice but i have multiple invoice that i why i am using scroll view..

Comment: can i pass my scrollview to above method by type casting?
(UIView *)self.scrollView can pass my scrollView like this?

Comment: Your sequence should be like scrollview - ContainerView - (anything - any number of view).  If you pass containerview then all subview covers in it.

Comment: Yes sir exactly. that is why i am confusing. I want to use that same visual representation as UIView holds. that is why i want to convert it into PDF.